# Bootstrapping Angular 2

Tags: angular, bootstrapping

I've been watching some tutorials on Angular 2. I'm confused on bootstrapping components. If I want to create multiple page applications, and don't need that root component, how would I go about doing that? I see how it would work for single page applications.

This is my Main.Ts File.

```
import { bootstrap } from 'angular2/platform/browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

Here is my app.component.ts file.

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core'; 

@Component({
    selector: 'pm-app',
    template: '<h1>{{PageTitle}}</h1>'
})
export class AppComponent {
    PageTitle: string = "Test";  

}
```

If I wanted to navigate to a page other than let's say index.html, and have it load a different component without bringing in the AppComponent, how would I go about doing that? In Angular 1+, it was easy since I just referenced the controller on the HTML page that I wanted to use. How would I just reference the component I want to use on a different page?

Thanks. Trying to wrap my head around angular 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some component always has to be that root component.

There is no need that it is always the same component. You can also bootstrap multiple components at one page, but each Angular2 application starts at some element, and that's the root component that is initialized with

```ts
@NgModel({
  ...
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

The view of that element can contain other elements and directives which make up the whole application.

Comment: So should I bootstrap all my components in the main.ts file? Or just bootstrap 1, and somehow overload it with all my components.. neither sound good. Does that mean if I have like 10 other components inside the root component that it loads the entire application each page, or only what it needs?

Comment: Usually you have one root component that makes up the whole page (that's how imagine the typical Angular2 application - there are other variants of course) and the view of this root component consists of other components and the view of these components again of others. You only need to bootstrap the component that wraps your application. Components inside the view of the root component are instantiated by Angular automatically. I'm not sure what you mean by "each page". Normally you use a router that inserts other components at specific marker elements inside your application

Comment: depending on the active route.

Comment: Just dont like that I have to shove every single component inside another component to get it to work. Seems like a cluster. If I have 10 components, i have to include them in the root component..

Comment: Try to embrace it. You'll have to adjust your view about how web applications are built with Angular2. If you just want to enrich some input here and there or implement a menu in Angular in an otherwise PHP generated page (or similar), then you probably don't use Angular2 as intended. Check the tutorials at angular.io. They are quite good.

Answer (score 0):

Angular 2 is very good in loading the component and that's why it is 5 times faster than angular 1. IT does not load all the component at one go It will load the required component only as the concept of Lazy Loading. For dynamic loading it uses the feature of Systemjs and also Webpack can be used.

Angular 2 is modular in design hence if you application has many modules. You can create multiple modules and bind all the modules into single root module.

Then you can use angular 2 routing feature. Which load the required module depending on the which route user clicked.

You can learn routing from in deep from here

```
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html
```